# How to store list of string in serenity screenplay

Tags: java, serenity

So I just recently migrated to serenity 4.1.3 from 2.0.30 and I'm trying to do this:
`List<String> x = Text.of(ThePage.element()).viewedBy(actor).asList();`

and this is what I'm trying to do in 4.1.3:
`List<String> x = actor.asksFor(Text.of(ThePage.element()).asListOf(String.class);`

but i get the error "java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.list"